# response not being received/sent? On a POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently working on a school project to make a webapp and have come across this problem. Where a response isn't being received (I assume) because the moment I use the "res" object it causes the page to show a "Cannot POST /editProfile" error. Going back a page and submitting the form a second time does not bring show the error. Everything is fine on backend with the object in the database being updated even on the first submit of the form.

Here is the code for it..

```
 $.post('/updateName', {username:Uname}, function(res){
     if(res.status == 200){
       alert("Name Successfully Updated");
       window.location.href = "/profile";
     }
       else{
         window.location.href = "/";
     }
 })
```

Code on the backend from the controller

```
exports.update_profile = function(req, res){
   cModel.update_profile(req.session.id, req.body, function(result){
       res.send({status:200});
   });
}
```

While writing this I have found that there is no issue when running the webapp on Microsoft Edge, the issue showing up on Chrome. I'm not exactly sure what to do at this point.

Comment: To debug AJAX requests open devtools, go to the network tab, then make the request. IT should appear in the list. You can click on it and see the response code, and any data it contained. Normally this will be enough information to debug the problem. Without that, we cannot really help you.

Comment: Could you add more code, the issue could lay outside of this snippet. Possibly this is inside an event handler of some sort?

Comment: Do you have a `status` property inside your returned data from the backend endpoint, more specifically the `res` parameter? If not, you should use a second parameter in the callback, which gives you the status code. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Following @RoryMcCrossan, I've checked the network tab of the devtools and upon the first submission of the form there is only one request in the list. A request for the edit name page and the request method being POST. Not sure whats going on there